# Numerical Approximation of the CMB Anisotropy Monopole $\Theta_0$ and the Scalar Metric Perturbation $\psi$

Tags: cosmology, computational-physics, cosmic-microwave-background

TL;DR:

- How can $\Theta_0+\psi$ be modelled, what are viable Ansätze for this, including numerical factors?

<sup>$\Theta_0$ being the temperature fluctuation monopole and $\psi$ being the scalar metric perturbation.</sup>

## Setting the Scene: CMB Anisotropies

The Planck Collaboration gave us the powerspectrum of temperature anisotropies in harmonic space:

$$
\frac{l(l+1)}{2\pi}C_l.
$$

In theory, we have

$$
C_l=\frac{1}{2\pi^2}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}k}{k}P(k)\Theta^2_\text{l}(\eta_0,k)
$$

with the powerspectrum $P_k$ given by

$$
P(k)=A_s \left(\frac{k}{k_0}\right)^{n_s - 1},
$$

where the amplitude of the primordial scalar powerspectrum $A_s=2.097\cdot10^{-9}$, the tilt / the spectral index $n_s=0.9652$, as well as the pivot scale $k_0=0.05$ are computed by the Planck collaboration [[Cosmology]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.06209.pdf).

This means that we have numbers for $C_l$ and $P(k)$ for $l\in(2,2507)$ and $k\in(10^{-5},10)$.

## Main Question

Now, my question is: Do we also have numbers and approximations for $\Theta^2_\text{l}(\eta_0,k)$? If so, what are they?

## What I have so far

$\Theta_l$ is often split into two parts in the following way:

$$
\Theta_l(\eta_0,k)=\int_{\eta_\text{ini}}^{\eta_0}S_T(\eta,\,k)j_l(k(\eta_0-\eta))\mathrm{d}\eta,
$$
where $j_l(k(\eta_0-\eta))$ are spherical Bessel functions and $S_T(\eta,\,k)$ is often called the temperature source function. This leads me to the following two questions:

### Sub-Question a: Dimensions of the argument of the spherical Bessel function

The argument of the spherical Bessel function should be dimensionless. But $k$ is in h/Mpc, where $h\approx0.7$ and $\eta$, the conformal time, is usually in Gyr, with $\eta_0\approx 46$ Gyr and $\eta_\text{dec}\approx1$ Gyr the values today and at decoupling. Is there just a factor of $c=306$ Mpc/Gyr missing, or is there more going on than just dropping $c$ in natural units?

### Sub-Question b: Modelling of the temperature source function $S_T$

The temperature source function is mostly split into three effects: the Sachs-Wolfe effect, the Doppler effect, and the integrated Sachs-Wolfe effect in the following way

$$
    S_T(\eta,\,k)=g\left(\Theta_0+\psi\right)+\left(gk^{-2}\theta_b\right)^\prime+e^{-\eta}\left(\phi^\prime+\psi^\prime\right).
$$

I found two Ansätze to simplify this:

1. The dominant effect is the Sachs-Wolfe effect.
2. The structure of the CMB is imprinted/frozen at decoupling.

The first point is easy to implement (just ignore the contributions from the Doppler effect and from the integrated Sachs-Wolfe effect). The second point means that the integral over $\eta$ does not need to be performed. The expression can simply be evaluated at $\eta_\text{dec}$. This leads to the following expression:

$$
\Theta_l(\eta_0,k)=\left(\Theta_0+\psi\right)\cdot j_l((k(\eta_0-\eta_\text{dec}))
$$

Now, my final question is: how can $\Theta_0+\psi$ be modelled, what are viable Ansätze for this, including numerical factors?

Comment: For subquestion a, the answer is that (as you thought), $k\eta$ is dimensionless in units with $c=1$. (However, note that if you use ${\rm Mpc}$ for length and ${\rm Gyr}$ for time, then $c\neq 1$, so the numerical values you have given in your answer are not in a natural unit system). For your main question, is this not covered in standard texts, for example [Baumann's notes](https://cmb.wintherscoming.no/pdfs/baumann.pdf) that are free online?